# ServiceStack: How to deal with user registration

Tags: mongodb, servicestack

I'm trying to understand how to create a `SignIn`/`SignUp` service with ServiceStack and my database of choice is MongoDB:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("My Web Services", typeof(WelcomeService).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] {
            new BasicAuthProvider()
        }));
        Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mongodb"].ConnectionString;
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("auth");

        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(new MongoDBAuthRepository(db, true));
    }
```

The code above works correctly... it connects to the MongoDB server and creates the user table in the `auth` database. So far so good... What I'm trying to understand is how the built-in registration service works. If you look at my code, I enabled the `RegistrationFeature` but when I try to invoke it with `http://localhost/register` I always get a `NotImplementedException`. Does this mean I have to implement it from scratch? Is there any additional package to install? How do I actually invoke the default registration feature?

Comment: try to set up db as singleton, move your plugin declarations at the end of the configuration